# Maximum number of cliques of size $\ge 2$ of a graph with exactly $m$ edges

Tags: clique, upper-bound

Let $G=(V,E)$ be an undirected graph with $|E|=m$ edges.

Given that any clique of size $\ge 2$ can be identified with its corresponding edges, and at most every subset $S\subseteq E$ creates a clique, $G$ can have at most $|P(E)|= 2^m$ cliques of size $\ge 2$.

However, based on the intuition that it's better to arrange the edges into bigger cliques, I'd assume arranging the $m$ edges into one big clique of size $c$ is optimal (whenever it's possible). If $c$ is the size of that clique, we have $m=\binom{c}2 \rightarrow c\le 4\sqrt m$, and I'd therefore assume that one can get an upper bound of the form $2^{4\sqrt m}$.

How would one show this upper bound?

Noting in above simple proof that only subsets $S$ with size $\left|S\right|=\binom{i}2$ for some $i\in \mathbb N$ can ever be edge sets of a clique doesn't seem to help.

Comment: I would try to show that a maximum number of cliques can be achieved when the $m$ edges are incident on as few vertices as possible (which is a clique when $m$ is a triangular number). I would try to do this by showing that, given an arbitrary $m$-edge graph, if there is a vertex $v$ all of whose incident edges can be moved to other pairs of vertices that are already both of nonzero degree (note there is a wrinkle for neighbours of $v$), then doing so (which reduces the total number of vertices incident on any edge, bringing us closer to a clique) never reduces the number of cliques.

Comment: You can take a look at similar proofs of Turán's theorem for inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0602191v4) paper with DOI 10.1007/s00373-007-0738-8 we have the following theorem:

> Let $n$ and $m$ be non-negative integers such that $m ≤ \binom n2$.
> Let $d$ and $l$ be the unique integers such that $m =\binom d2+l$,
> where $d ≥ 1$ and $0 ≤ l ≤ d − 1$.
>
> Then the maximum number of cliques
> in an $(n, m)$-graph equals $ 2^d + 2^l + n − d − 1$.

Here, an $(n,m)$-graph is a graph with $n$ nodes and $m$ edges.

This graph has $n$ 1-cliques and $1$ 0-clique.

Therefore its number of cliques of size $\ge 2$ is
$$
 2^d + 2^l  − d − 2 \le  2^{d+1} − d − 2\le 2^{d+1}
$$
and $d$ is the biggest integer with $m\ge \binom{d}2$.

So we further have
$$
d\le \frac{\sqrt{8·m+1}+1}2
$$

Assuming $m\ge 1$, we have
$$
\frac{\sqrt{8·m+1}+1}2\le \frac{\sqrt{9m}+1}2 = \frac{3\sqrt m+1}2\le 2\sqrt m
$$

And with that, we get that the number of cliques of size $\ge 2$ is upper bounded by
$$
2^{2\sqrt m+1}=2\cdot 4^\sqrt m
$$